# Remove HTML tags in JSON result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to access a JSON result from jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/App/QueryString.jsp?Query="+query,
  contentType:"text/html; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(json) {
    if(data!=""){
      console.log(json);
      var data = json.Json;
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
});
```

But this is giving me result with HTML tags in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body> JSON:[Includes the result]</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the json output but enclosed with HTML tags. I just want to remove them and get the json result only.

Can somebody help me on this?
Does it have something to do with the dataType and contentType?

Comment: I guess you will have to do `JSON.parse(json.body)`. Also, you can look into `$.getJSON()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use:

```
contentType:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

This asks for HTML format. Change that to:

```
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

And you should get the raw JSON back.

Comment: When I try this, it is not giving me any response.

Comment: Do you get any error? Are you sure your back end is handling the `contentType` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `contentType` property. You have set it to `text/html; ...` which returns you the html structure. Try removing the `contentType` from your request or setting it to `application/json; charset=utf-8` to get raw JSON output.